# RS232 cannot be discovered as /dev/ttyS* or /dev/ttyUSB* on ubuntu of wsl 2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, serial-port, embedded

I'm having problem to get serial connection using RS232 (to USB) and picocom of wsl. From Windows I can see that my RS232 is using `COM24` and from `lsub` on wsl I can also see my RS232. However, if I do `ls /dev/tty*`, I can see `/dev/tty[0...63]` and `/dev/ttyS[0..3]`, but neither `/dev/ttyS24` nor `/dev/ttyUSB24`.

I checked with `stty -F /dev/ttySx -a`, but all visible `ttyS` gave me `stty: /dev/ttySx: Input/output error`

Does anyone have any idea how to figure out which `dev` is mapped to my RS232?

On a side note: I also tried with a UART board and it does give me a serial communication, in this case, wsl2 maps the UART to `/dev/ttyUSB0` although it's identified as `COM6` on Windows.

Comment: A USB-to-RS232 adapter would have a device node named **/dev/ttyUSB**n.  But before that device node can be created, the adapter has to be properly recognized and its driver installed. Look for messages pertaining to those events in the syslog, e.g. use the **dmesg** command after plugging in the adapter.

Comment: @sawdust Unfortunately I don't get anything from `dmesg`

Comment: "WSL2: Ubuntu 18.04 Serial devices are no longer mounted properly" https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4322